# Strange fonts when opening tex file

Tags: miktex, texworks

I have a Dell XPS 15 with MikTex 2.9 installed. For some reason, and without reason, when I open a tex file within TeXworks, the fonts looks like chinese (see graphic).  Oddly, it compiles fine.  If I create a new file and open the original file in notepad, and paste the original text from notepad to a new file within TeXworks and then try to Typeset the file I get a "Undefined control sequence."  The crazy looking file is attached.  I am not having this problem on my desktop nor do I have this problem if I open this same file in TeXStudio.

Thoughts on what could be causing this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Note:  I never had a problem prior to today and I have been using MikTeX on my laptop for about 3 weeks now without an issue.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: It looks like you opened the file with a different encoding _e.g._, your file is `utf8` and you opened with `utf16`, or something like that. See if you can reopen the file with the correct encoding (most likely `utf8`).

Answer (score 1):

Like Phelype Oleinik already said, it seams to be the wrong encoding. You can change the Enconding like that:

Edit->Preferences->Editor

There is an option called 'Encoding' choose UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  On my desktop it is UTF-8.  I changed the default on my desktop to UTF-8 (it was something different.)   However, I get strange characters, although a different set of characters.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to open the file with another editor? - Whats the result?